# iPhone iOS how to send an HTML email with CSS styling?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, css, ios

I need to send an HTML report with images from an application. The report is laid out and an image is embedded within the report. **When I preview the report in a web view, it appears correct, when I receive it by GMail, the styling and image is missing.**

There's a CSS stylesheet embedded within the header.

I'm sending out a report like this:

```
NSString* htmlReportString = [ReportManager createReportWithEvent:event];
[mailController addAttachmentData:[htmlReportString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] mimeType:@"text/html" fileName:@"report.html"];
[mailController setMessageBody:htmlReportString isHTML:YES];
```

Here's what I get out of a .plist and append as a report header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>template1</key>
    <string>
&lt;!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd&quot;&gt;
&lt;html xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;&gt;
&lt;head&gt;
&lt;meta http-equiv=&quot;Content-Type&quot; content=&quot;text/html; charset=UTF-8&quot; /&gt;
&lt;title&gt;Report&lt;/title&gt;
&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;
.statHead {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
}
.statSub {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #FFF;
}
.repHead {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}
.repSub {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
}
.repLinks {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
}
.repSubBullet {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
    list-style-type: circle;
}
.repSubBold {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}
.topName {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}
.topDate {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
}
.topSub {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;
}
&lt;/style&gt;
&lt;/head&gt;

&lt;body&gt;</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

When I **preview the report within iPhone's web view, it appears correct** - all styles are present, the image is present. But **when I receive the report in GMail, the image is missing and none of the styles are showing**. If I save the report and view it on my Mac's preview app, the report is displayed correctly once again.

**What is causing this issue? Is it an encoding/ backslash issue or does Gmail treat HTML differently than Apple's web browsers?**

Comment: Your XML seems incomplete - there is no </dict> ...

Comment: There were a couple styles in the XML, I did not copy the second style, there is </dict> after that. I updated the question with the closure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have escaped HTML specialchars in your HTMl code, `&lt;` etc. should be replaced to their official HTML equivalents, otherwise your HTML won't work. That it's working in the iOS browser sounds for me a bit strange.

Of course it could be also another problem...

Answer (score 0):

Merge your CSS with the HTML page and make a complete String of data. Then add the following code.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *picker=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate=self;
    [picker setSubject:@"Your Title"];
    [picker setMessageBody:HTMLSTRING isHTML:YES];
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];
```

View this in your mail composer. Is it displaying correctly?

Comment: The HTML is displayed correctly in the safari on iPhone and Mac preview tool. If I open GMail within safari on Mac, the styles are not there and there's no image.

Comment: Is the HTML visible correctly in the mail composer of the phone or not?

Comment: Yes, the HTML is correctly visible when the email is composed. It is when it is received by the email app (Gmail) when it stops displaying images and styling

Comment: @AlexStone yes Gmail stop displaying images and css. It does not displays the content of Facebook and twitter's mail. You need to press the button of display images at the corner in gmail.